# Configuring UICollectionView to keep the same cell view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view delegate

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UICollectionViewCell {
}
```

I wanted the property of the cell to persist between each call to this method.

```
let cell = levelView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier,
      forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

But retrieving cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` seems to create a new cell view element that is different from the initial one.

```
cell.accessibilityIncrement()
```

So the cell accessibility value cannot persist after tapping on the cell.
I need to do this because I wanted to do UI testing by tapping on the cell.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Reusable cells in iOS are handled with a queue. This helps the tableViews and collectionViews move smoothly and remain efficient with a large amount of data. I don't think you would want to change the way that is designed to work in your application. This way, the device only needs to load as many cells into memory as can be displayed on a single screen. As cells move off the screen, they can be reused as another cell as `cellForItemAtIndexPath` will be called to load the required data into the reused cell.

If the goal is to have a value persisted between cell reloads, consider using a map or some other similar variable that could be managed by the collectionView's dataSource delegate.

For example, in your viewController that contains your dataSource delegate, you could have a `Dictionary` defined like so:

`let numberOfTapsByIndexPath = [NSIndexPath: Int]()`

Then every time a cell is tapped, you would increment the value in the map for the cell tapped. That code might look something like this:

`let previousTaps = numberOfTapsByIndexPath[indexPath]
numberOfTapsByIndexPath[indexPath] = previousTaps + 1`

I'm not 100% sure that was the goal you explained above, but regardless, you'll want to move any persistent information out of the cell and into a variable that the dataSource delegate or some other singleton can manage.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, my goal is to do a UI testing, I wanted to check if the backgroundView property of the cell changed. I am not sure if it is worth it to add an extra variable just for testing. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: If you just need a unique identifier on each cell for accessibility consider assigning the accessibility identifier to something that can be determined in code such as `cell.accessibilityIdentifier = "CollectionCell-\(indexPath.section)-\(indexPath.item)"`